# Python selenium - Using browser.find_element_by_id() isn't finding object with ID

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am having a bit of a problem with Selenium. I am new to Selenium, web scraping and Python as a whole. I am doing a practice project where I can send emails straight from my IDE.

I have been able to enter things into the 'send to', 'cc', and 'subject lines' well. I am having a problem entering body text.

Here is a screenshot of my email/inspect element:

[image: Here is a screenshot of my email/inspect element]

As you can see in this image (pixelized by Stack Overflow, but I think you can get the idea.) The body is one big box with the ID 'tinymce'. The code block representing this text input is:

```html
<body
    id="tinymce"
    class="mce-content-body mce-inactive-editor"
    data-id="ZmHtmlEditor1_body"
    contenteditable="true"
    style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 696px; height: 212px;" data-mce-style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: #000000;"
    dir="LTR"
    aria-label="Compose body">

    <div><br data-mce-bogus="1"></div>
</body>
```

My code, to open the text box, is

```python
# Email body text
content = pyit.inputStr(prompt='What is the body of your email?\n')

clickBodyText = browser.find_element_by_id('tinymce').click()
bodyText = browser.find_element_by_id('tinymce').sendKeys(content)
```

I click on the body text first to make the input active, and sendkeys of the content. This returns the *no such element* error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="tinymce"]"}
(Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.125)
```

Comment: Was the linebreak in attribute "style" in the original HTML content?

Answer (score -1):

To send a *character sequence* within the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using a CSS selector:

  ```python
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body.mce-content-body.mce-inactive-editor#tinymce"))).sendKeys(content)
  ```
- Using an XPath selector:

  ```python
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//body[@class='mce-content-body mce-inactive-editor' and @id='tinymce']"))).sendKeys(content)
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports:

  ```python
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```python
find_element_by_id()
```

or

```python
find_element_by_xpath()
```

but the error will be same if the element is not loaded before the execution of the command. For that, you can use the following method:

```python
import time

time.sleep(5)
```

Use *time.sleep* after you open a webpage so it can be loaded fully before performing any operation.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem - my entire website was already loaded beforehand. I had a similar problem earlier on in the project which is used time.sleep() with, but the page is already loaded for this.

Comment: if you want to insert anything in the input area you don't need to click on it
you can simply send keys to the textarea element

Comment: that might be so but i still cannot find the element.